# Cloning a laptop drive with bootable Windows installation

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, clone, liveusb

I have a laptop (Acer Swift 3) where I am trying to replace its 123GB M.2 drive with a larger 256GB drive. Ideally I want to clone the drive, including the Windows 10 installation.
Since the laptop only has one M.2 port I cannot clone the drive directly. So what I am trying to do is to clone the original drive to an external 256GB SSD and then to clone from that to the new M.2 drive.

I have used **EaseUS Todo Backup** for the cloning process since it came recommended on several websites. The cloning (from the original M.2 drive to the external SSD) seems to go well and all three partitions are recreated and the data seems to be all there. However, the system partition is not bootable, so I am not able to boot up from the external drive and clone to the new M.2 drive, which was my original idea. Or rather, it does try too boot up, but at some point Windows says it is not able to.

Now I need advice on how to proceed. I either need a way to make the external drive bootable, or a way to clone the drive in a way that will preserve all of the properties of the partitions.

I have actually tried to make several Live CD USB installations (**Runtime Live CD**, **Clonezilla** and **GParted**) but for some reason all of them seem to just stop at some point during the boot-up. I have tried creating them both manually and using creation tools, with same effect. Perhaps I am downloading the wrong versions - perhaps it's something else.

**EDIT:** I have now successfully cloned the disk using Clonezilla, but it still fails to start and the Windows repair tool is not able to fix the issue.

Comment: Buy an M.2 to usb adapter and clone that way.

Comment: @Moab I might end up doing that, although I hope I can avoid it. However, right now my issue is that I am not able to make a successful bootable clone in the first place.

Comment: But you are cloning to one drive then to another, this strategy is not working. Windows will not boot from external usb media.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in reply, I had to wait for another drive to arrive. You were correct that the issue was that Windows could not boot up from an USB drive. I was however able to use the external drive as an intermediary in order to clone to a new M.2 drive. If you write your comment as an answer I will accept it.